# Django: type object 'CategoryAttributeInlineForm' has no attribute: '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 2 models: `Categories` and `CategoryAdditionalAttributes` that has foreign key to `Categories`.

Also, I'm creating an inline form set for `CategoryAdditionalAttributes`, but I meet this error in the testing phase:

**models.py**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    category_breadcrumb = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'assortment'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_breadcrumb


class CategoryAdditionalAttribute(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
    Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='additional_attributes')
    attribute_key = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    attribute_value = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'assortment'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(str(self.attribute_key), self.attribute_value)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(str(self.attribute_key), self.attribute_value)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CategoryAdditionalAttributeInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryAdditionalAttribute
        fields = ['attribute_key', 'attribute_value']

    def save_new_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_attributes = super(
            CategoryAdditionalAttributeInlineFormSet, self).save_new_objects(commit)
        if commit: 
            CategoryAdditionalAttributeService()
             .insert_additional_attributes(saved_attributes, self.deleted_forms)

        return saved_attributes

    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_attributes = super(
        CategoryAdditionalAttributeInlineFormSet, self).save_existing_objects(commit)
        if commit: 
            CategoryAdditionalAttributeService()
             .insert_additional_attributes(saved_attributes, self.deleted_forms)

    return saved_attributes


class CategoryAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryAdditionalAttribute
    formset = CategoryAdditionalAttributeInlineFormSet
    extra = 1


class CategoriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoriesForm
    search_fields = ['category_breadcrumb']
    inlines = [CategoryAttributeInline]
```

**test**

```
class CategoryAdditionalAttributesTest(TestCase):
    ....
    def test_insert_additional_attribute_success(self):
        AttributeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
            Categories, CategoryAdditionalAttribute, form=CategoryAdditionalAttributeInlineFormSet)
        data = {
            'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
            'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
            'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
            'form-0-category': self.test_category,
            'form-0-attribute_key': 'a_room',
            'form-0-attribute_value': 'Kamar Mandi'
        }

        test_attribute_formset = AttributeFormSet(data)
        self.assertEqual(test_attribute_formset.is_valid(), True)
```

**Results**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/varian/.local/share/virtualenvs/f1-thanos- aRnD22rB/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/varian/Desktop/dekoruma/f1- thanos/thanos/apps/assortment/tests/test_admin.py", line 134, in test_insert_additional_attribute_success
    test_attribute_formset = AttributeFormSet(data)
  File "/home/varian/.local/share/virtualenvs/f1-thanos-aRnD22rB/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 885, in __init__
    if self.form._meta.fields and self.fk.name not in self.form._meta.fields:
AttributeError: type object 'CategoryAdditionalAttributeForm' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Any help will be appreciated.